# I'm trying to rewrite the 4 functions below into a single function

Tags: javascript

```js
function ingredientsHover() {
  document.getElementById('ingredients').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
}
function ingredientsNormal() {
  document.getElementById('ingredients').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
  // document.write("Normal");  
}
function preparationHover() {
  document.getElementById('preparation').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
}
function preparationNormal() {
  document.getElementById('preparation').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
}
```

Comment: And what problem did you encounter? Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: What is the problem with combining such functions? You must be more specific in why a general solution didn't/isn't working and include such a thing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single function which accepts the element id and a value for fontSize. Inside the function pass the element id as variable to `document.getElementById`

```
function ingredientsStyling(elem, styleVal) {
  document.getElementById(elem).firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = styleVal;
}
ingredientsStyling('ingredients', '300%');
```